# How to find a sound bite amoungst a collection of sound files?

Tags: mp3, wav, sound-editing

Salvete!  I have a sound bite where a person is speaking a particular phrase.  Now, I have copied that sound bite and pasted it into several other sound files.

Now I need to find all the files into which that sound bite has been copied.

How can I find them?

I have a collection of mp3 and wav files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we finally were able to test the programs and *Similarity* from http://www.similarityapp.com/ does everything we need it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Because you did that with an sound-editor most probably the file got re-compressed and the byte sequence may not be the same through all the files.

But if you know the period in which you modified those files you may search all the files modified in that time span, it should not be too many, unless you are doing this often.

Comment: Not a bad idea. I'll pass that on to my fellows, and if that solves it, I'll mark your answer, but you get my +1 for now!

Comment: Sorry so long!  I'm still looking into this.